# Resolving Type Mismatch with ScalaJson Serialization

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a controller class where i have placed a writes object to serialize my user object. Unfortunately, there is an error for when retrieving user.getId:

```
type mismatch; found : Long required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper 
Note: implicit value userWrites is not applicable here because it comes 
after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
```

Here is my code:

```
object UsersController extends Controller {   

  implicit val userWrites = new Writes[User] {
    def writes(user: User) = Json.obj(
      "id" -> user.getId,
      "username" -> user.getUsername
    )
  }

  def users = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.users()) 
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why the error says, "Note: implicit value userWrites is not applicable here...", because if I get rid of the user.getId portion, the error goes away.

What do I need to do get rid of this error and properly create a Writes object for my User class.

Comment: What does `User` look like? Does `getId` not have an explicit result type? It seems like that's what the scala compiler is trying to tell you--in which case, you should provide one so the `implicit Writes[Long]` or whatever can be resolved.

Comment: User is a java object, so yes it returns a Long. That's why it says, "found: Long"

Comment: The fact that `User` is a java object and not scala object was critical to mention, because that's most likely the root of the problem. It's having trouble finding what type to serialize `user.getId` to.

Comment: Why would it have trouble finding what type to serialize a Long to? The compiler knows that user.getId is a Long. Why would it matter if it was a java object or not, compiler will just check the .class files anyways and so it really doesn't matter if it is a scala or a java object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Java Long is not a Scala Long and Play's Scala JSON serializers only support Scala types. You can convert explicitly via `Long2long`:

```
implicit val userWrites = new Writes[User] {
  def writes(user: User) = Json.obj(
    "id" -> Long2long(user.getId),
    "username" -> user.getUsername
  )
}
```